# does the JFrog Xray trial have any limitations?

Tags: jfrog-xray

I'm running a evaluation of JFrog Xray at work and I'm wondering if there are any limitations applied to the trial version? 
The reason I'm asking is because it does not display all CVEs reported to components (struts2-core-2.5.1). 
I can see that the public snyk.io DB has all CVEs but Xray does not display them all.

Anyone had the same experience?

Answer (score 1):

JFrog Xray with a trial license has not limitation in term of functionality, please make sure that the vulnerabilities and components database sync is fully completed and up to date (you can check the **db sync status** on the home page), before starting the scanning process, at any case if you find a mismatch or something is not clean  you can approach Jfrog support for help